# Sending Form Data after redirect with CURL

Tags: curl

I'm Sending a file with curl:

```
curl https://localhost/input.php --insecure -L --form "id=myId" --form "file[]=@/tmp/myFile"
```

This is working fine as long as I'm writing the http**s** (and no redirect is performed)
When I write the `http://localhost/input.php`, The Webserver redirects with a 302 to the https site. `curl` follows that link, but `curl` wont "resend" the form data to the target.

How can I tell curl to resend the FORM Data, even after a 302 redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Found myself the answer:

```
 --post302
```

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--post302